# Close/edit/delete/flag bar in 2 rows

Tags: bug, firefox

It is possible for the actions bar to span 2 lines.  It is particularly disorienting when the `(1)` and the action that it corresponds to are on different lines.  (in this case `close`)

[image]

Comment: The same happens when there are positive number of reopen votes *and* delete votes.

Comment: @AmalMurali all caused by same root problem of missing non-breaking spaces, allowing the overflow.